# How can I style the thead and tbody for this page?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML page with the CSS included. The CSS works for certain parts of the page, but not the parts I discuss. I want to have a background color and make a few other style changes, but they aren't implementing.

Here is the CSS:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr, table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th { background-color: #e6EEEE; font-size: 8pt; padding: 4px; }
table.tablesorter thead tr .header { cursor: pointer; }
table.tablesorter tbody td { padding: 6px; vertical-align: top; border-bottom: dashed 1px #333; }
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td { background-color: #F0F0F6; }
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp { background-image: url(images/asc.gif) no-repeat; }
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown { background-image: url(images/desc.gif) no-repeat; }
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp { background-color: #8dbdd8; }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Pilot ID</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Total Flights</th>
    <th>Total Hours</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $pilotcode; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $userinfo->rank;?></td>
    <?php
    if($report)
    { ?>
        <!--<td><strong>Latest Flight: </strong><a 
                href="<?php echo url('pireps/view/'.$report->pirepid); ?>">
                <?php echo $report->code . $report->flightnum; ?></a>
        </td>-->
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $userinfo->totalflights?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $userinfo->totalhours; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

All this results in is bold text with plain text below it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your CSS is applying the styles to a table with the class tablesorter. Simply add this to the table tag

```
<table class='tablesorter'>
table content
</table>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7q4U/)